# wp7 'new app' list in the marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I recently had my app certified (first time!) but not automatically published. The game is Easter themed and hence I'd like it to appear in the new list over the Easter period. I need to know how best to achieve this.

According to many posts online, the 'new list' isn't sorted in order of release date but instead, in order of certification date, an automated system, the certifiers choice etc.

Thre are some theories here:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/85466.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536557/first-time-game-shows-up-way-down-the-list-of-new-free-games-on-wp7-marketplace

Both of these posts are in 2011 and aren't conclusive.

Does anybody know what ACTUALLY happens?

Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the new apps are changed once per day or in a similar fashion. Again, from experience, you can't do anything to ensure that your application is first. However, I have manually published applications after they have been tested and approved and they were listed in the 'new' category as if they were published that day.

Usually, don't worry because your app will be listed in the first 20 of that 'day' at least once and if you get - or set ;) - some high ratings people will see it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this out the hard way. The plan was to release to a few small markets to get some feedback and then do an update and release to the USA. Well, once the game was released to the USA it was not considered new and did not go into the NEW GAME list. It retained the release date of the initial release to the small markets. And as such, I totally missed out on the new release spike that we all have come to love and enjoy.

[Check out Alien Escape](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=b37b78f9-7a80-4fde-8daf-c4a0c32e35e5)

Game Trailer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWE6Dlk6xpc

Answer (score 0):

I have some apps on marketplace already. I can talk from experience. The release after you have published will depend on countries and will delay without fully control. Also if you don't make any advertisement, it will not work with only **"keywords on marketplace"**. I have solved by using my **own Webservice** and I flagged the app with "**LOCKED**" view. On EASTERN you can unlock the app by using your Webservice flag and immediately when the app starts, user can use it **UNLOCKED**.

[image: App is locked]

No other solution is working in time usable way. But I fully like it to have my own app under **full control**. Also, I have added an "**Code behind**" for Testers to let them test the app **before EASTERN**.

Happy eastern